# How to get youtube title with xpath

Tags: xpath, youtube

Following code does not get youtube title. It worked before. What's wrong?

```
from lxml import etree

def get_youtube_title(youtube_id):
  youtube_watch_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
  youtube_watch_url += youtube_id

  youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen(youtube_watch_url).read().decode('utf-8'))
  #video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")  # old youtube? Worked before. Not work recently.
  video_title = youtube.xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string')  # xpath copied from Inspect menu "copy | copy xpath" by right click tile in html.

  return ''.join(video_title)


print(get_youtube_title('2wEA8nuThj8'))
```

Result is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of keeping the things dependent on the things which could change over time, such as css classes or other ids which could change over time, extract the title from `<title>`

```
from urllib import request
from lxml import etree


def get_youtube_title(youtube_id):
    youtube_watch_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
    youtube_watch_url += youtube_id
    youtube = etree.HTML(request.urlopen(youtube_watch_url).read().decode('utf-8'))
    return youtube.xpath("//title")[0].text if len(youtube.xpath("//title")) > 0 else "NO Title"


print(get_youtube_title('2wEA8nuThj8'))
```

Comment: @Sdhant Rajora. I am trying to understand where to find 'title' in youtube page, as I also want to extract video length and time of post. Thank you again.

Comment: <title> tag is only for extracting the title of page, thus it works for the said question, but if you want to extract the other details such as length of video, time of upload, you will have to look for the tags or elements that shows that data on the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

`yt-formatted-string` element is added by JS, so you cannot extract its text from source code.

Try to extract title from `meta` node:

```
video_title = youtube.xpath('//meta[@name="title"]/@content')
```

Comment: Hi JaSON, Can you explain why meta work, why xpath copied from Chrome | Inspect does not work? Thank you again.

Comment: @user3792705 that's because you're scraping the **source code** while XPath copied from **page rendered by Browser**. Note that while rendering page Browser executes JavaScript that might add some new nodes into HTML-tree, e.g. `yt-formatted-string`